# rspec expecting empty routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm implementing an API on my app, and testing it with Rspec.

my items controller doesn't have the `new` or `edit` actions, and the routes.rb has no routes for them:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :items, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
end
```

My rspec test for them looks like:

```
it "raises error on #new" do      
  expect(:get => "/api/v1/items/new").to have_http_status(404)
end
```

but when I execute the tests on it I get:

```
Api::V1::ItemsController routing raises error on #new
 Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/api/v1/items/new").to have_http_status(404)
   expected a response object, but an instance of Hash was received
 # ./spec/routing/items_routing_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this case and get the test to pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`be_routable`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher) matcher:

```
it { expect(get: '/api/v1/items/new').to_not be_routable }
```

From docs:

> The be_routable matcher is best used with should_not to specify that a
>   given route should not be routable. It is available in routing specs (in
>   spec/routing) and controller specs (in spec/controllers).

As a workaround for the issue with `new` being interpreted as `show`, you can use alternative matcher called [`route_to`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher):

```
it { expect(get: '/api/v1/items/new').to_not route_to('/api/v1/items#new') }
```

or

```
it { expect(get: '/api/v1/items/new').to_not route_to(controller: '/api/v1/items', action: 'new') }
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, as the path get interpreted and `new` get's considered as the `id` for the `show` action: `expected {:get=>"/api/v1/items/new"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:format=>"json", :controller=>"api/v1/items", :action=>"show", :id=>"new"}`

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a hash to expect:

```
{ :get => "/api/v1/items/new" }
```

but your assertion is only valid for response objects. You probably want to do something along the lines of

```
get "/api/v1/items/new"
expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
```

but if you haven't defined that route yet, this test will probably fail as well.

See [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher) for documentation on the have_http_status matcher.

Comment: I tried that, but rspec says that `undefined local variable or method `response'`